# CIS benchmarks compliance translated to ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-16.04, inspec

I’ve been discovering inspec lately and I’m trying to translate some CIS benchmarks to ruby scripts that I can execute using InSpec.

The thing is that I’m not familiar with ruby, by any chance, can I use another language for coding those scripts ?
I’ve been following a youtube tutorial from chef :

Create a Profile - What to expect when you're InSpec'ing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0npgDsES9s

I couldn’t even install atom correctly on ubuntu 16.04,

Did anone face the same issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to know `ruby` to use `inspec`. You could try using the resources like [Compliance Automation With Inspec](https://learn.chef.io/tracks/compliance-automation#/) on Learn Chef. That website has all the resources you need to learn everything Chef related.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use another language for coding those scripts?

No.

From the documentation:

> The InSpec DSL is a Ruby DSL for writing audit controls, which
>   includes audit resources that you can invoke.

[https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/dsl_inspec/]

At a minimal, you must learn the Ruby DSL in order to write InSpec tests.  And if you also learn Ruby, you'll be able to write a lot of additional tests that can't be done with the Ruby DSL alone (though it is quite capable).  Ruby is a simple scripting language with a host of tutorials on the web; I suspect you'll be able to pick it up in no time.